# what should I do for a heavy report using stimulsoft?

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I have a heavy report it takes 2 or 3 minutes for initializing load how I can set my report to load first page and then by clicking every page a progress appear and load another page.

Comment: Have you seen Stimul.Report for web it exactly thing I need on every page load there is rendering and then show it so it caused much better performance.

Comment: What viewer do you use? Which version?

Comment: 2012.2.1304.0 but it is not the viewer issue please look at this : http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1247&p=5201    but after clicking the next page it gives me error. "You need to rebuild the report on each page refreshing or need set property RenderMode of the StiWebViewer to 'UseCache' or 'AjaxWithCache'."

Answer (score 3):

for this error " "You need to rebuild the report on each page refreshing or need set property RenderMode of the StiWebViewer to 'UseCache' or 'AjaxWithCache'"

you must set your StiWebViewr RenderMode Property to one the list opened below.

the renderMode list have such this items ==> ajaxWithCatch,UseCatch and etc./.